# How to monitor qdisc bandwidth utilization

Tags: monitoring, tc

I have created a script to shape my traffic using tc.
Is there any tool in Linux which will help me to visualize and monitor qdisc bandwidth
utilization ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tc information:

```
    tc -s qdisc ls dev $DEV
    tc -s class ls dev $DEV
```

You can use any language to process the tc output.